# If you keep the torch inside your inventory, will their fire extinguish?

Tags: legend-of-grimrock

You keep the torch inside your inventory, say for a long time...

Will it be useless, or it can still be used?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A torch kept in the inventory can still be used later.  Torches will be automatically lit when equipped in a character's hand, and extinguished (along with their light) when dropped or stored in the inventory.  You can unequip and re-equip a torch as many times as you like, lighting is done automatically and doesn't require any other items or materials.

Torches will only burn down when equipped, so you should swap dying torches for fresh ones from the wall mounts around the dungeon as you go.

I like to give one of my characters a wooden box full of torches to carry around, just for emergencies.  You can also use burnt out torches as weapons (if you have nothing better), as well as objects to place on buttons and switches.